# I can't create an XML file in Eclipse

Tags: xml, selenium-webdriver, testng

In Eclipse I right click a project "WebDriverTest1" and the "Select a Wizard" window is displayed.

In the "Select a Wizard" window I can type xml but nothing is displayed that will allow me to select xml.

An instructor on a Utube WebDriver video could easily create an xml file that would then allow a WebDriverTest incorporating TestNG modules to be executed but I had no option to create the xml file.

Comment: Have you created the xml and want to select it or you want to create one?

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed an XML plugin for eclipse?

Until you install a plugin, that's how it'll be.
Eclipse supports almost anything, but only a few things "out of the box".

Webtools Platform:
http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/sse/

XMLBuddy:
http://download.cnet.com/XMLBuddy/3000-7241_4-10405546.html
Tut with XMLBuddy:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecxml/

Vex:
http://www.eclipse.org/vex/

Rinzo:
http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/